Is there a closed form solution to $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{\binom{N-1}{n}x^n (1-x)^{N-n-1}}{n+1}$
Is one able to derive a closed form solution for:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{\binom{N-1}{n}x^n (1-x)^{N-n-1}}{n+1}$$
If it helps we know that
$$\sum_{n=0}^N \binom{N}{n}x^n (1-x)^{N-n} = 1$$

There is a typo in your binomial formular.... Should be $(1-x)^{N-n}$.

Thank you! That's exactly right.

Consider the fact that $$\int_0^1t^n\ \mathrm dt=\frac1{n+1}$$ We use this and write \begin{align*}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{\binom{N-1}{n}x^n (1-x)^{N-n-1}}{n+1}&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{n}x^n (1-x)^{N-n-1}\int_0^1t^n\ \mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{n}(xt)^n(1-x)^{N-n-1}\ \mathrm dt\\&=\int_{0}^1(xt+1-x)^{N-1}\ \mathrm dt\\&=\frac{(1+xt-x)^N}{Nx}\bigg|_{t=0}^1\\&=\frac{1-(1-x)^N}{Nx}\end{align*}

Thank you so much! This is a neat solution.

Your expression equals
$$
(*)=x^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} (1-x)^{(N-1)-n}=\frac{f(x,1-x)}x
$$
where
$$
f(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} y^{(N-1)-n}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{n}x^n y^{(N-1)-n}=(x+y)^{N-1}
$$
by the binomial theorem.
Since $f(0,y)=0$,
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{(x+y)^N-y^N}{N}
$$
and thus
$$
(*)=\frac{f(x,1-x)}{x}=\frac{1-(1-x)^N}{Nx}.
$$

Thank you so much! This is an awesome solution. I was definitely not on track to figuring this out!

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{\binom{N-1}{n}x^n (1-x)^{N-n-1}}{n+1}
&= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{N}{n+1}x^n (1-x)^{N-n-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \binom{N}{n}x^{n-1} (1-x)^{N-n} \\
&= \frac{1}{Nx} \sum_{n=1}^N \binom{N}{n}x^n (1-x)^{N-n} \\
&= \frac{1}{Nx} \left(\sum_{n=0}^N \binom{N}{n}x^n (1-x)^{N-n} - \binom{N}{0}x^0 (1-x)^{N-0} \right) \\
&= \frac{1 - (1-x)^N}{Nx}
\end{align}
